# Como se compara uma string quando ela só tem um espaço?

Tags: php, string

Gostaria de comparar minhas variáveis, para validar um formulário:

```
if ($nome or $categoria or $rua or $numero or $bairro or $abre or $fecha or $email or $telefone == " ") {           
    echo"Tente novamente</b>, faltou preencher corretamente um ou mais campos do formulário.";
}
```

Porém, o `echo` dentro do código não é executado.
Descobri que uma ou mais, destas variáveis contém um espaço em branco!

Como posso corrigir esta validação?

Comment: Não está muito claro qual sua duvida

Comment: Agora a questão ficou esquisita, eu queria comparar variável por variável. Essa era a dúvida. O @dvd resolveu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está tentando comparar todas as variáveis ao mesmo tempo usando apenas 1 operador `==`. Isso não funciona. Você teria que comparar as variáveis uma por uma, desta forma:

```
if ($nome == " " or $categoria == " " or $rua == " " or $numero == " " or $bairro == " " or $abre == " " or $fecha == " " or $email == " " or $telefone == " "){
   echo "Tente novamente</b>, faltou preencher corretamente um ou mais campos do formulário.";
}
```

Mas você pode usar outra forma criando uma array com as varáveis e depois verificando uma por uma com um `foreach` para ver se alguma delas é igual a um espaço em branco:

```
$posts = array($nome, $categoria, $rua, $numero, $bairro, $abre, $fecha, $email, $telefone);
$valido = true;

foreach($posts as $item){
    if($item == " ") $valido = false;
}

if(!$valido){
   "Tente novamente</b>, faltou preencher corretamente um ou mais campos do formulário.";
}
```

Comment: Cara, era exatamente isso que eu queria! Só uma observação: só funcionou sem o espaço entre as aspas no meu formulário. Era extatamente isso! Obrigado! ;-)

Comment: Deve não ter funcionado com o espaço entre as aspas porque estou usando várias funções(trim, preg_replace e ucwords) antes das comparações. Mas num código normal funcionou perfeitamente. Sobre o que você disse, eu sou novo no fórum, mas pode deixar que a partir de hoje passarei a assinalar a resposta correta. De novo, muito obrigado por ter entendido a pergunta!

Answer (score 4):

Isso é simples de resolver, é só deixar apenas as aspas sem o espaço e colocar as variáveis dentro da função trim(negada):

```
if (!trim($nome) or !trim($categoria) or !trim($rua) or !trim($numero) or !trim($bairro) or !trim($abre) or !trim($fecha) or !trim($email) or !trim($telefone)) {
    echo"2 - Tente novamente</b>, faltou preencher corretamente um ou mais campos do formulário.";
}
```

Uma forma mais completa, desta forma ele verifica se é nulo ou vazio:

```
function verificaCampos(array $campos){
    foreach($campos as $campo){
        if(empty(trim($campo)) or is_null(trim($campo))){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

$nome = 'ok';
$categoria = 'ok';
$rua = 'ok';
$numero = 'ok';
$bairro = 'ok';
$abre = 'ok';
$fecha = 'ok';
$email = 'ok';
$telefone = 'ok';

$campos = [
    $nome, 
    $categoria, 
    $rua, 
    $numero, 
    $bairro, 
    $abre, 
    $fecha, 
    $email, 
    $telefone
];

if (!verificaCampos($campos)) {
    echo"Tente novamente</b>, faltou preencher corretamente um ou mais campos do formulário.";
}
```

Comment: Eu não quero comparar se a variável é vazia, quero comparar se ela é igual a um espaço. Estou tentando validar um formulário e quero que campos com somente um espaço não passem.

Comment: porque não usa trim?

Comment: Coloquei um outro código que não deixa isso passar.

Comment: Já usei o trim e mesmo assim passa com somente um espaço. Tenho a leve impressão de que o trim não limpa o espaço, mas sim os espaços em volta do espaço. Mas eu usei e não funcionou.

Comment: Este segundo código que eu postei trata isso.

Comment: Testei com trim aqui e funcionou.

Comment: Se `trim` retornar uma *string* vazia, o PHP avaliará como falso, então no primeiro trecho de código da resposta, se um ou mais campos estiverem preenchidos, entrará no `if`, o que pode não fazer sentido (principalmente quando todos estiverem preenchidos). Acredito que, neste caso, o `trim` deveria ser negado. O último `trim` também está englobando o operador de comparação.

Comment: Testei assim e o trim não funcionou, dá que é igual: <?php

$nome = "Click Fome";
$bairro = "Jardim Margarida";
$categoria = "Açaí";

if(trim($nome) or trim($bairro) or trim($categoria) == " ") {
 echo "É igual";
} else {
 echo"É diferente";
}

?>

Comment: Foi um teste, perceba que era para cair no Else.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss obrigado pela dica, fiz a alteração, aproveitando, queria te agradecer, você é o cara que mais pegou no meu pé aqui até hoje, no começo eu não entendia direito, pensava que você estava com alguma coisa contra mim, mas isso me fez crescer muito. :)

Comment: @dvd teste com && e não funcionou, as vezes estou interpretando errado, se qualquer uma for vazia ele entra no if.

Comment: Mas eu não quero assim: se todas forem iguais. Quero assim: se uma delas for igual. Se uma delas for igual a " ", cai no else. É assim que quero.

Comment: É isso mesmo, se qualquer uma estiver vazia, ela entra no if, se uma ou mais estiver vazia entra, se todas estiverem preenchidas não entra.

Comment: Testes: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7dd411768bca09ecc25ba8799893e53edb4dd29c